# boto3 import fails python3.4

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to come up with python script, to get instance's Tag key `AutoScalingGroupName` value of the instance. I already installed `boto3` using `pip3`.

from python3.4 shell I was able to `import boto3` successfully.

```
#python3.4
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jul  8 2016, 11:37:17)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> exit()
```

but the script fails with this error.

```
#python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import boto3
ImportError: No module named boto3
#
```

here is the content of the `test.py`

```
# cat test.py
#!/bin/python3.4
import requests
import boto3
import botocore.session
import urllib.request

instid = urllib.request.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read().decode()
autossession = botocore.session.Session(profile='auto1')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
autosval = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds={instid}, Filters={"tag:AutoScalingGroupName"})
print(autosval)
#
```

Comment: Here is an article showing how to install boto3 with Python 3.4 using virtualenv: [How do I create an isolated Python 3.4 environment with Boto 3 on Amazon EC2 using virtualenv?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/python-boto3-virtualenv/)  That might help you debug your situation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, boto3 is already installed. See the first section of the code, `Import boto3` in python3.4 shell has no errors.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I just noticed I am running the script as `python2.7` instead of `python3.4`. I am not seeing `ImportError: No module named boto3`

Comment: Follow @JohnRotenstein advise, use virtualenv.  This is the number 1 best practice for python development. Installing pypi inside generic environment need `sudo` access, this mean you cannot load boto3 without `sudo python`. Virtualenv will created isolated localised user environment and let you install python package without `sudo`

Comment: Thanks @mootmoot, sure will start using Virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your problem is caused by **running different versions of Python** from the command line vs scripts.

This is quite common when there are multiple versions of Python (and its libraries) installed on a system.

I, too, have experienced problems when installing python libraries and utilities via the `sudo` command (eg `pip`), but then having different paths between users so different versions would run.

Fortunately, the Python community has created [**Virtualenv**](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), which allows multiple versions of Python to be installed, **each within its own environment**. This also allows the installation of libraries without requiring `sudo` access.

If you're still experiencing version mismatches, give virtualenv a try!